# Negative Boost SolrJ bq

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am writing parameters into a bq query via a solrj implementation application. Some of my fields I want to negative boost (i.e. (id: -abc123)^3) as shown [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F) but whenever I search I get logging errors:

> "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse"

and it shows the query exactly as it should be written (and how it works from the web applet). Why won't it parse properly in SolrJ but will via HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query like:

```
bq=(-id:abc123)^3
```

Boosts everything other than doc with id=abc123.

You can try to reduce score of that document with query like:

```
bq=(id:abc123)^0.3
```

In project I'm working on at tied that, but at the end of the day I used boosting during indexing (I'm doing that based on document "class"). That solution works for me just fine.

Comment: placing the negative ahead of the field versus the value did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't advise using BQ as it is an additive boost. It's rather hard to predict the influence as it depends on term frequency and overall query score. You can try using the BOOST parameter with function value inside, like if(exists(query({!v='id:abc123'})),1/3,1) - so that the document having abc123 has its score multiplied by 1/3

Comment: hmm that does seem like it could be a better fit. a few questions regarding syntax: what does the final argument (the 1) represent? also, do I need single quotes for my ID strings? I also need to put in multiple IDs, how would I write that? would I use an OR operator?

Comment: the meaning is to put 1/3 if the value exists and 1 otherwise. Since it's multiplicative 1 means no boost, 1/3 means negative boost. If you have several ids, you may use OR - it's a regular query syntax.